# HTML5 Drag & draw letter but within a contained area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, draggable

I need to allow dragging a pointer on a predefined area. Refer to the following image.

1) The arrow needs to be moved along the dotted lines only.

2) Also, I need to detect when the arrow pointer has reached the end of the dotted line.

How to achieve this? Using jQuery draggable or do I need to use HTML5 Canvas?

[image: the arrow needs to be moved along the dotted lines]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried to create this and tell us what's wrong.

Comment: https://codepen.io/MAW/pen/aOzeNR <-- Not my code but maybe it will help you get an idea for your project

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Just trying to find out what's the best possible approach.

Comment: @FrankGroot this seems like a possibility. Will give this a try and let you know. Thanks. Appreciate your help.